# Permutation test (Пермутационный тест aka рандомизация aka точный тест). Условия применения?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, комбинаторика, статистика, теория-вероятностей

Мой вопрос в большей степени вызван отсутствием русскоязычных источников.. :(

Недавно столкнулся с одним методом симуляции статистической гипотезы как пермутационное тестирование (также называется рандомизацией и точным тестом). В контексте того , где я узнал об этом методе, выдвигалась гипотеза об идентичном распределении рассматриваемых показаний (результаты выборов по муниципалитетам в двух регионах) и статистическим критерием этой гипотезы было равенство среднего процента голосования за кандидата.

Суть метода состояла в следующем: Два массива размерами n и m сливались в один, далее хаотично менялся порядок элементов и просто первые n элементов назначались первым массивом , а оставшиеся-вторым. Считался стат.критерий и такое перемешивание проводилось большое число раз.

Однако мне осталось непонятными обоснованность этого метода и для каких гипотез его можно применять?

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь, что вы тут найдёте больших спецов в статистике. Вам надо на какой-то более специализированный форум, думаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассмотренный вами метод имеет право на жизнь. Суть его в следующем. Предположим, обе выборки вытягиваются из одной генеральной совокупности. Понятно, что полученные характеристики двух выборок будут различаться, но вот вопрос, их различие случайно, либо может быть признаком того, что на самом деле они вытягиваются из разных ген.совокупностей.
Что бы проверить это можно выполнить пермутационный тест, сделав несколько (сот) тысяч циклов моделирования, посчитать распределения полученных параметров выборки, построить их функцию распределения а потом посмотреть, ваш исходный результат согласуется с этим распределением или нет.